# Using Visual Studio keymap in PyCharm. Looking for PDF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pycharm, keymapping

I sometimes write some Python code using PyCharm IDE 
[official web site](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

As a .NET developer I'm familiar with Resharper's keymap in VS, and I really like It. I found out that PyCharm supports VS keymap (It can be found in IDE Settings - Keymap) and I'm interested in using It, BUT, on theirs official web page, I mentioned above, they provide no PDF with VS keymap...Maybe someone is using VS keymap in PyCharm? Did you find any keymap PDF-s ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only default keymaps are available in the official PDF files, we don't have PDF for Visual Studio keymap. You will have to create it yourself and share with the community =)

**UPDATE**: there is now a [Keymap Exporter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7066) plug-in available that can export current keymap into PDF.

Comment: Thanks, I hope It will be available in the near future

Comment: Where would be a good place to share it? @taras.roshko What is the status of this work.

Comment: @CrazyCoder : any plans for a visual studio keymap that is more true to the VS / R# combo? (e.g. Ctrl-R, M for extract method and all of the usual). I find it quite difficult to switch because the keymaps are quite different.

Comment: @MarkSimpson, please submit this kind of requests directly to [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: @CrazyCoder : shall do -- sorry for asking here, not the best place I agree. I quickly made my own in the meantime :)